# How to send JSON data to server and get JSON/XML as response using JSP

Tags: javascript, json, jsp

I am a beginner for web application. I created  a dynamic web project using java EE on glassfish server. Now I want to let client send data using json to server and receive data from server using json or xml. By searching online, I am now clear with how to program on server side. Now I use ajax to send json data. However, maybe it's to easy to code on the server, I can't find any code related to server. My server side should use JSP to read the json data, using a bean(finished) to generate some data and send the data back. Here is the code and I don't where is the problem. Can anyone give any advice to me? your help means a lot for me!

this is the ajax code on the client side. I sent two input number from a form

```
$(function() {
    $("#myform").submit(function() {
        var lat = $("#num1").val();
        var lon = $("#num2").val();
        alert("form");

        if (num1 == '' || num2 == '') {
            $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
            $('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "marker.jsp",
                contenttype : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data : {
                    "num1" : "wtf",
                    "num2" : $("#num2").val(),
                },

                success : function(msg) {
                    $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                    $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    alert(msg);

                }
            });
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

but after I switch to the jsp page, I only found two null values displayed, here's the code on the server, I planned to send xml at the beginning and I am not sure whether the request.getParameter can work and how to send back these xml data or using json format to send the data back. Help!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<%@ page contentType="text/xml" %>
<%@ page             import="javax.naming.InitialContext,net.roseindia.ejb3.stateless.*,javax.ejb.EJB,java.util.*"%>
```

```
<%
        try {

            String s1 = request.getParameter("num1");
            String s2 = request.getParameter("num2");
    %>
            <%=s1%>
            <%=s1%>

    <%
            if (s1 != null && s2 != null) {
                List<String> textdatas = cal.GetTextResults(s1, s2);

                for (String textdata : textdatas) {

                String textLocation= "("+textdata.split("\\t",2)[0]+")";
                System.out.println(textLocation);
    %>
    <text>
        <location><%=textLocation%></location>
        <event> <%=textdata.split("\\t",2)[1]%></event>
    </text>
    <%
                }

                List<String> images = cal.getImage();

                for(String image: images){
                System.out.println(image);
    %>          
    <image>
        <imglocation><%=image.split("\\t",2)[0]%></imglocation>>
        <path><%=image.split("\\t",2)[0]%></path>
    </image>



    <%          
            }
            }
        }// end of try
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //result = "Not valid";
        }
    %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using any MVC framework I suggest you to adopt one. It doesn't seem that rendering an XML/JSON from a JSP is a good/easy practice. Its not difficult to see that your code its getting too cumbersome... not to say that it might not be valid code.

I suggest that you adopt a MVC framework - I use [VRaptor](http://vraptor.caelum.com.br/en/) which is quite a good and simple one, allows you to develop RESTful web apps without even being aware of it. Make sure to check this [one minute guide](http://vraptor.caelum.com.br/documentation/vraptor3-one-minute-guide/)!!! This framework by encapsulating [ThoughWorks XStream Framework](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) makes it dead simple to accomplish your task. Take a look at what would be needed to respond to a request with a JSON object:

```
    import static br.com.caelum.vraptor.view.Results.*;

    @Resource
    public class ClientsController {

    private final Result result;
    private final ClientDao dao;

    //result and dao parameters gets inject by VRaptor that
    //by its turn lets you chose which Dependency Injection framework
    //you wouldd like to be using with - pretty much as a plugin
    public ClientsController(Result result, ClientDao dao) {
        this.result = result;
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    @Get("/client/json")
    public void loadJson(MyParam param) {
        result.use(json()).from(dao.getClient(param.id)).serialize();
    }

    @Get("/client/xml")
    public void loadXml(MyParam param) { 
        result.use(xml()).from(dao.getClient(param.id)).serialize();
    }
}
```

Note that Vraptor deserializes MyParam object from JSON and also injects it to your controller action request arrives!

This example was taken from [this page](http://vraptor.caelum.com.br/documentation/view-and-ajax/)!

Comment: Thank you. But sorry I forgot to mention I use j2ee and glassfish server

Comment: Its not a problem, you can run a mvc framework over this configuration too! :)